# Tax in US on interest earned from NRE account

Tags: united-states, income-tax, india, international

I work in the US and recently got converted to H1B. I am planning to transfer funds to my NRE account ($3000), accrue interest in 3-4 months and then use it to pay for my student loan. Will I be taxed for the interest accrued on the NRE account here in the US? If yes, how much is the tax?